# Difficulty generating valid transactionIDs for IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

- A) I am trying to implement Apple In-App-Purchases for a new iOS
  app/game.
- B) I have a client-server application, and the purchase validation and entitlement grant needs to happen on our game-server. As best as I can tell, I want to use Get Transaction History to validate the purchase on the game server.

I'm testing a sandbox app/APIs using TestFlight. My generated transactionID's are sequential integers starting at 0, but some documentation suggests it should be a UUID. So far, the integer transactionID/originalTransactionID have not yielded a valid response from GetTransactionHistory.

The errors I get are:

- {"errorCode":4000008,"errorMessage":"Invalid original transaction id."}
- {"errorCode":4040005,"errorMessage":"Original transaction id not found."}

I'm mostly stumped at this point, as I can't find any documentation describing what I may have missed, and there are no other forum posts or search results for those error codes.

So my questions:

1. Will GetTransactionHistory ever this work with sequential integer transactionIDs?
2. I've deployed the signed app through TestFlight, and I'm still getting sequential integer transactionIDs. Is that expected? What am I doing wrong?